# Visual Studio 2008: Smoothly switch between Emacs and default keybindings

Tags: visual-studio, emacs, pair-programming

Is there any way in Visual Studio 2008 to smoothly switch between using Emacs keybindings and the default ones? I will soon be doing some pair programming and I need my Emacs keybindings to keep myself from going insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new VS macro and add this code :

```
Sub ToggleEmacsKeyBindings()

    Dim emacsSchemeName As String = "Emacs"
    Dim defaultSchemeName As String = "(Default)"

    Dim props As EnvDTE.Properties = DTE.Properties("Environment", "Keyboard")
    Dim propsItem As EnvDTE.Property = props.Item("SchemeName")

    Dim previousScheme As String = propsItem.Value

    If propsItem.Value = emacsSchemeName Then
        propsItem.Value = defaultSchemeName
    ElseIf propsItem.Value = defaultSchemeName Then
        propsItem.Value = emacsSchemeName
    End If

    MsgBox("Previous Scheme: " + previousScheme + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "New Scheme: " + propsItem.Value)

End Sub
```

You can then [assign a keyboard shortcut to this macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62%28VS.80%29.aspx) to more quickly and easily toggle between `Emacs` and `'Default'` keyboard scheme.

(Note: This works in VS 2005 and have not tested in VS 2008 but it should work too. It also works in VS 2010 with the [Emacs emulation extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/09dc58c4-6f47-413a-9176-742be7463f92) installed.)

Answer (score 1):

[VisEmacs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/visemacs/) lets you edit files using Emacs, from within Visual Studio. So you don't have to switch keybindings at all! Some more useful information on VisEmacs is [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/VisEmacs).

Comment: I'm writing ASP.NET MVC and therefore I'm extremely dependent on the Intellisense in Visual Studio. I don't suppose VisEmacs supports this, does it?

Comment: @deniz VisEmacs do not support Intellisense!!