# I'm getting an error in the console when using gitkraken but the solution runs perfectly and the file is not showing the >>>>>HEAD line error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, gitkraken

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIJ7a.png)

Hi, I'm getting the next errors but it looks like a bug because the project runs ok. It says:

Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea
Error       Files tiene un valor "<<<<<<< HEAD" no válido. Caracteres no válidos en la ruta de acceso.  CendyLib    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4381

But when I click on the error the file looks correct.

Anyone know what could be the problem?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to search the entire solution for the value and remove it from where it occurs, and then delete the obj folder from your project. When you build again it should work.

The obj folders are hidden in Visual Studio. You can see them with a file explorer.

Reference from: [Error MSB3541: Files has invalid value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906647/error-msb3541-files-has-invalid-value)