# visual studio 2013 auto recover breakpoints and bookmarks

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I get a bluescreen of death or a locally installed program freezes my computer and I have to reset VS does a nice job of recovering the text files I'm editing.  Unfortunately it loses all the breakpoints and bookmarks I have saved, they seem to revert make to an early state from weeks before.  Is there a way to autosave/autorecover bookmark and breakpoint.  Sometimes this results in days of work lost.

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints (and probably bookmarks) are stored in the .suo file. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873839/why-are-there-sln-suo-and-csproj-files).

It's not recommended to commit these to a version control repository but you could [write a script to copy the file to another directory location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986447/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-one-folder-to-another-folder), then [run that script as a scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler).